Problems with updating TYPO3 to V12
Typo3 11.5, news 11.4, eventnews 6.0.2, container 2.3.6, PHP 8.2
The module "Scan extension files" results in severe errors in news and container, even after having de-installed custom extensions.
container:

Classes/Command/SortingCommand.php Method "run()" supports only 0 arguments. (weak)
Classes/Command/SortingInPageCommand.php Method "run()" supports only 0 arguments. (weak)
Classes/Command/IntegrityCommand.php Call to method "error()" (weak)
Classes/Hooks/TableConfigurationPostProcessing.php Usage of class "TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\TableConfigurationPostProcessingHookInterface"
(strong)
Classes/Updates/ContainerMigrateSorting.php Method "run()" supports only 0 arguments. (weak)
Classes/Updates/ContainerMigrateSorting.php Method "run()" supports
only 0 arguments. (weak)
Classes/View/ContainerLayoutView.php Fetch of property "id" (weak)
Classes/View/ContainerLayoutView.php Fetch of property "id" (weak)
ext_localconf.php Access to array key "extTablesInclusion-postProcessing" (weak)
ext_localconf.php TYPO3\CMS\Core\Package\PackageManager::__construct requires at least 1 arguments (0 given). (strong)

The above is also true in another installation.
news:

Classes/Controller/AdministrationController.php Usage of class "TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\BackendTemplateView" (strong)
Classes/DataProcessing/AddNewsToMenuProcessor.php Fetch of property "sys_page" (weak)
Classes/ViewHelpers/MetaTagViewHelper.php Fetch of property "recordRegister" (weak)
Classes/ViewHelpers/MetaTagViewHelper.php Fetch of property "recordRegister" (weak)
Classes/ViewHelpers/MetaTagViewHelper.php Fetch of property "recordRegister" (weak)
Classes/ViewHelpers/TitleTagViewHelper.php Fetch of property "recordRegister" (weak)
Classes/ViewHelpers/TitleTagViewHelper.php Fetch of property "recordRegister" (weak)
Classes/ViewHelpers/TitleTagViewHelper.php Fetch of property
"recordRegister" (weak)

eventnews:

Classes/Controller/NewsController.php Fetch of property "id" (weak)
Classes/ViewHelpers/RedirectViewHelper.php Use of static class method call "TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\HttpUtility::redirect()" (strong)
Tests/Unit/Hooks/IconHookTest.php Method "run()" supports only 0
arguments. (weak)

An update to TYPO3 12 resulted in Installtool and Backend showing severe errors in the browser console (something with "eval could not be processed").
All relevant caches have been cleared on many occasions, before and after the update.
For me it looks like these extensions aren't yet ready for TYPO3 v12
Anybody any advice?

Can't speak for ext:eventnews but the versions you've listed for ext:news and ext:container are definetly ready for TYPO3 12. What errors do you get exactly? Did you also run the upgrade wizard? Maybe try to manually disable these extensions by removing them from /typo3conf/PackageStates.php and then run the scanner

If you have a Composer-based installation you have no PackageStates.php anymore. Then remove the extensions via Composer.

did you try with original TypoScript and Fluid Templates of the extensions? If you have adjustments and / or conditions in own files, even the conditions beside the adjusted templates themselves can throw errors.

We have all three listed extensions running in production with TYPO3 v12 and PHP 8.2... Can you provide some more details (eg more accurate messages)?

@Wintermilch: I was not able to run the Upgrade wizard: I got an unspecified error, nothing logged in typo3.log

@David: That's what I thought first, but the errors didn't disappear after de-installing my custom extensions.

As TYPO3 Integrator you should be more precise in your questioning please. Did you run "Scan extension files" in TYPO3 11 or 12? Which versions of news etc... did you install under TYPO3 12?

As I wrote in my question: the TYPO3 version is 11. "Scan extensions" is run under TYPO3 11! TYPO3 12 crashes already in the install tool, no error logs, only in browser console.

I had to de-install all extension. Then the update of the bare TYPO3 instance was possible. After that I could re-install the extensions.
